# Issue with firebase realtime DB, equalTo() with react native expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I am trying to randomize a node in my database to query out based on **ShopNo**

But I am unable to get the node I need when using **equalTo**. I am only able to get a randomize value based on how many **Shop** I have in my database. Can anyone help out with this?

Part of my database:

```
{
  "Bakery": {
    "Bakery Cuisine": {
      "Description": "Within North Spine Plaza",
      "Halal": "Yes",
      "Latitude": 1.34714,
      "Location": "50 Nanyang Ave, #01-20 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 639798",
      "Longitude": 103.68066,
      "OH": "Mon - Sat : 8 AM to 7 PM, Sun Closed",
      "ShopNo": 1
    }
  },
  "Beverage": {
    "Beverage": {
      "Description": "Within the South Spine food court",
      "Halal": "No",
      "Latitude": 1.34253,
      "Location": "21 Nanyang Link, Singapore 637371",
      "Longitude": 103.68243,
      "OH": "Mon - Fri: 7 30 am to 8 pm, Sat - Sun/PH Closed",
      "ShopNo": 2
    },
    "Beverages": {
      "Description": "Within North Spine Koufu",
      "Halal": "No",
      "Latitude": 1.34708,
      "Location": "76 Nanyang Dr, #02-03 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 637331",
      "Longitude": 103.68002,
      "OH": "Mon - Fri : 7 am to 8 pm, Sat : 7 am to 3 pm, Sun Closed",
      "ShopNo": 3
    },
    "Boost": {
      "Description": "Within North Spine Plaza",
      "Halal": "No",
      "Latitude": 1.34735,
      "Location": "50 Nanyang Ave, #01-11 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 639798",
      "Longitude": 103.68036,
      "OH": "Mon - Fri : 10 am to 9 pm, Sat - Sun: 10 am to 6 pm",
      "ShopNo": 4
    },
"Total": 89,
}
```

Total contains the amount of Shops (Child) I have in the DB. With this Total, I am able to generate a random value but when I tried to query the database I get the following error:

[image]

I have a feeling my syntax is wrong in this issue but I cant figure out the right syntax

My code:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import {db} from '../firebase'
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {ref, get, orderByChild, equalTo} from 'firebase/database'

const SubScreen2 = () => {
  
  
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  
  const [todoData, setToDoData] = useState([])
  
  
  useEffect (() => {
    var random = 0
    get(ref(db, "food/Total")).then(snapshot => {
      const count = snapshot.val();
      random = Math.floor((Math.random() * count));
      console.log(random) //Random number generated (Successful)
      ref(db, `food/`), orderByChild("ShopNo"), equalTo(random)  //Failed
      .then(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.val() 
        setToDoData(data)
      })
    
      
  },[]) })
  console.log(todoData)
```

Update: Changing from ref(db, `food/`), orderByChild("ShopNo"), equalTo(random) to query(ref(db, `food/`), orderByChild("ShopNo"), equalTo(random)) and also importing query from firebase/database
as it couldnt find the variable for query

```
import {ref, get, orderByChild, equalTo, query} from 'firebase/database'
const SubScreen2 = () => {
  
  
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  
  const [todoData, setToDoData] = useState([])
  
  
  useEffect (() => {
    var random = 0
    get(ref(db, "food/Total")).then(snapshot => {
      const count = snapshot.val();
      random = Math.floor((Math.random() * count));
      console.log(random)
      query(ref(db, `food/`), orderByChild("ShopNo"), equalTo(random))
      .then(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.val()
        setToDoData(data)
      })
    
      
  },[]) })
  console.log(todoData)
```

I still get the error - TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...ualTo)(random)).then(function (snapshot)...')

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong:

```
ref(db, `food/`), orderByChild("ShopNo"), equalTo(random)  //Failed
.then(snapshot => {
  ...
```

You're [missing a `query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) here, and it should probably be:

```
query(ref(db, `food/`), orderByChild("ShopNo"), equalTo(random))
.then(snapshot => {
  ...
```

So you pass the reference, the ordering instruction and the filtering instruction to `query`, and then call `then` on the resulting promise.

Comment: I tried changing but it still didnt work though. It is giving me error. How come?

Comment: I just tried another method which is using the function get after query : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75624959/grabbing-the-wrong-item-from-firebase-realtime-database-via-react-native-expo but it is grabbing the wrong item in that case.