# Trouble with retrieving specific node in firebase realtime DB via react native expo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

New issue that appear after [Grabbing the wrong item from firebase realtime database via react native expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75624959/grabbing-the-wrong-item-from-firebase-realtime-database-via-react-native-expo)

Part of my database:
[image]

```
{
  "Bakery": {
    "Bakery Cuisine": {
      "Description": "Within North Spine Plaza",
      "Halal": "Yes",
      "Latitude": 1.34714,
      "Location": "50 Nanyang Ave, #01-20 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 639798",
      "Longitude": 103.68066,
      "OH": "Mon - Sat : 8 AM to 7 PM, Sun Closed",
      "ShopNo": 1
    }
  },
  "Beverage": {
    "Beverage": {
      "Description": "Within the South Spine food court",
      "Halal": "No",
      "Latitude": 1.34253,
      "Location": "21 Nanyang Link, Singapore 637371",
      "Longitude": 103.68243,
      "OH": "Mon - Fri: 7 30 am to 8 pm, Sat - Sun/PH Closed",
      "ShopNo": 2
    },
    "Beverages": {
      "Description": "Within North Spine Koufu",
      "Halal": "No",
      "Latitude": 1.34708,
      "Location": "76 Nanyang Dr, #02-03 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 637331",
      "Longitude": 103.68002,
      "OH": "Mon - Fri : 7 am to 8 pm, Sat : 7 am to 3 pm, Sun Closed",
      "ShopNo": 3
    },
    "Boost": {
      "Description": "Within North Spine Plaza",
      "Halal": "No",
      "Latitude": 1.34735,
      "Location": "50 Nanyang Ave, #01-11 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 639798",
      "Longitude": 103.68036,
      "OH": "Mon - Fri : 10 am to 9 pm, Sat - Sun: 10 am to 6 pm",
      "ShopNo": 4
    },
"Total": 89,
}
```

My code

```
const SubScreen2 = () => {
  
  
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  
  const [todoData, setToDoData] = useState([])
  
  
  useEffect (() => {
    var random = 0
    get(ref(db, "food/Total")).then(snapshot => {
      const count = snapshot.val();
      console.log(count)
      random = Math.floor((Math.random() * count));
      console.log(random)
      const rc = query(ref(db, `food/`), orderByChild("ShopNo"), equalTo(random))
      get (rc)
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((shopSnapshot) => {
          const shopKey = shopSnapshot.key;
          console.log("Hello")
          console.log("Randomly selected shop: " + shopKey)
          const shopData = shopSnapshot.val();
          console.log("Shop data", shopData);
        })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      })
      
      
    
      
  },) })
```

No errors reported in console but the only logs I get was

[image]

I tried catching the error but there was nothing appearing in my log. I am very confused about this. Why is there no error but at the same time, it cannot grab the node?

Using the same method but with function:

Code

```
const SubScreen2 = () => {
  
  
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  
  const [todoData, setToDoData] = useState([])
function getFirstChild(queryRef) {
  return get(query(queryRef, limitToFirst(1))) // mix in a query limit
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      let firstChild = null;
      querySnapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        firstChild = childSnapshot;
      });
      return firstChild; // DataSnapshot | null
    });
}
  
  
  useEffect (() => {
    var random = 0
    get(ref(db, "food/Total")).then(snapshot => {
      const count = snapshot.val();
      console.log(count)
      random = Math.floor((Math.random() * count));
      console.log(random)
      const rc = query(ref(db, `food/`), orderByChild("ShopNo"), equalTo(random))
      
  getFirstChild(rc) // rc being query(ref(db, "food"), orderByChild("ShopNo"), equalTo(random))
  .then((shopSnapshot) => {
    const shopKey = shopSnapshot.key;
    console.log("Randomly selected shop: " + shopKey)
    const shopData = shopSnapshot.val();
    console.log("Shop data", shopData);
  })
    })
  })

      
      
    
      
  },) })
```

I got a error of

[image]

Comment: How certain are you that `ShopNo` with the value of `random` exists? I'd recommend testing with `startAt(random)` and `limitToFirst(1)` to increase the chances you get a result.

Comment: Do you mean ```query(ref(db, `food/`), orderByChild("ShopNo"), startAt(random), limitToFirst(1))```. I tried this query but it didnt work. It only gives me the console.log of count and random. And for this ```random``` value, shouldnt it come from a value that count have?. ```random = Math.floor((Math.random() * count));``` from what I understand is to randomize a value from count. Or did I misunderstand something?