# Why is my Firebase realtime database query failing via react native expo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Can anyone explain to me how come my query to the database get nothing from the database?

Code:

```
useEffect (() => {
  var random = 0
  get(ref(db, "food/Total")).then(snapshot => {
    const count = snapshot.val();
    console.log(count)
    random = Math.floor((Math.random() * count));
    console.log(random)
    const rc = query(ref(db, `food/`), orderByChild("ShopNo"), equalTo(random))
    get(rc)
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((shopSnapshot) => {
          const shopKey = shopSnapshot.key;
          console.log("Randomly selected shop: " + shopKey)
          const shopData = shopSnapshot.val();
          console.log("Shop data", shopData);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
}, []);
```

Database (Part of it)

```
{
  "Bakery": {
    "Bakery Cuisine": {
      "Description": "Within North Spine Plaza",
      "Halal": "Yes",
      "Latitude": 1.34714,
      "Location": "50 Nanyang Ave, #01-20 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 639798",
      "Longitude": 103.68066,
      "OH": "Mon - Sat : 8 AM to 7 PM, Sun Closed",
      "ShopNo": 1
    }
  },
  "Beverage": {
    "Beverage": {
      "Description": "Within the South Spine food court",
      "Halal": "No",
      "Latitude": 1.34253,
      "Location": "21 Nanyang Link, Singapore 637371",
      "Longitude": 103.68243,
      "OH": "Mon - Fri: 7 30 am to 8 pm, Sat - Sun/PH Closed",
      "ShopNo": 2
    },
    "Beverages": {
      "Description": "Within North Spine Koufu",
      "Halal": "No",
      "Latitude": 1.34708,
      "Location": "76 Nanyang Dr, #02-03 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 637331",
      "Longitude": 103.68002,
      "OH": "Mon - Fri : 7 am to 8 pm, Sat : 7 am to 3 pm, Sun Closed",
      "ShopNo": 3
    },
    "Boost": {
      "Description": "Within North Spine Plaza",
      "Halal": "No",
      "Latitude": 1.34735,
      "Location": "50 Nanyang Ave, #01-11 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 639798",
      "Longitude": 103.68036,
      "OH": "Mon - Fri : 10 am to 9 pm, Sat - Sun: 10 am to 6 pm",
      "ShopNo": 4
    },
"Total": 89,
}
```

By right, this statement `` const rc = query(ref(db, `food/`), orderByChild("ShopNo"), equalTo(random)) `` should be getting the node that contains the ShopNo's value that matches the value of random but I am getting nothing at all with no errors. Is the syntax for the statement incorrect or am I missing additional codes?

Comment: Here is the food node in database?

Comment: Here? The JSON format I have provided in all under 'food' @Alex

Comment: I don’t think orderByChild works like that. I think you’d have to remove those category keys, “Bakery” and have a flat structure.

Comment: According to the video of: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4ZnTCi50bc I used for the reference and according to the guy who provided the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75624959/grabbing-the-wrong-item-from-firebase-realtime-database-via-react-native-expo, it seems it is possible but I couldnt contact him anymore after he posted the answer so I couldnt figure out @FreddieMixell

Answer (score 0):

ShopNo is in the depth path, maybe you can flat your database structure or split into multiple queries.

```
query(ref(db, `food/Bakery `), orderByChild("ShopNo"), equalTo(random))
query(ref(db, `food/Beverage `), orderByChild("ShopNo"), equalTo(random))
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it into a single query? This is because I am trying to randomize the cuisine and the shop by ```ShopNo```

Comment: As far as i know, firebase doesn't support this complex join queries.  For your case, you can choose to (one of three):
1. Flatten the data structure by placing the data under a single field.
2. Sort the data locally after querying.
3. Use the more powerful Firebase Cloud Firestore with advanced features.